# Connection Error when fetching update from Software Updater

Tags: 12.10, updates, software-updater

I checked for updates and got an error stating:

```
Failed to download repository information, Check your internet connection
```

and the details:

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.2)/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.2)/dists/quantal/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm running an OEM laptop, 32 bit 1 Gb Ram.

I looked at the settings and there was an option to add a CD-Rom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that you have selected the CD-ROM in software sources. doing so will check your CD-ROM for sources.  To uncheck CD-ROM option click on Software Sources, under System Settings, and go to the Other Software Tab, and Uncheck cdrom, as shown below:

[image]